# How do I find the maximum depending on multiple subranges within one column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables: Orders and Customers.
Orders lists all bought items (policy_id) and Customers information such as their age. The two tables are linked via the customer_id.
Now I want to find the most popular items within 3 age groups (18-30, 31-60, >60).
How do I approach this problem?

The following gives me a list of all items and their popularity split into the age groups but I only want the most popular ones per age group.

```
SELECT o.policy_id, count(o.policy_id) as ntotal, CASE  
    WHEN c.Age BETWEEN 18 and 30 then '18 - 30'
    WHEN c.Age BETWEEN 31 and 60 then '31 - 60'
    else 'above 60' end as RANGErrr    
FROM Orders o INNER JOIN Customer c ON (o.customer_id=c.customer_id)
GROUP BY RANGErrr, o.policy_id
```

Do I need to add something or am I on the completely wrong track?

Comment: Is `policy_id` a "type of policy"? So are you looking for a query giving 3 results - the policy_id with the max(ntotal) for each age group?

Comment: yes it's a type of policy and yes that is exactly what I am looking for

Comment: What if there are multiple `policy_id` with the same count for an age group - do you care then which one?

Comment: I am not sure. For now lets say no I do not care which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions for this.  You can do so right along with the aggregation.  For the top `policy_id` per age range:

```
SELECT co.*
FROM (SELECT co.*,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RANGErrr ORDER BY ntotal DESC) as seqnum    
      FROM (SELECT o.policy_id, count(*) as ntotal,
                   (CASE WHEN c.Age BETWEEN 18 and 30 then '18 - 30'
                         WHEN c.Age BETWEEN 31 and 60 then '31 - 60'
                         else 'above 60'
                    END) as RANGErrr
            FROM Orders o INNER JOIN
                 Customer c
                 ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
            GROUP BY RANGErrr, o.policy_id
           ) co
     ) co
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

If you want a different number, just change the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, but when I run the code it just adds one column "seqnum" filled with 1's

Comment: @Shef . . . The result set should have three rows, one for each age range.  Are you saying it does not have that?  Also note that your question refers to "items" but the query processes `policy_id`s.  One assumes these are the same thing.

Comment: . . Yes the result does not have three rows it has more. Still multiple per age group. And yes item = `policy_id`

Comment: @Shef . . . I don't think that `MIN()` trick works.  Arggh.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: thanks, it seems to work now. Could you only briefly explain what `seqnum` changes?

Comment: @Shef . . . I don't understand the question.  This version properly uses the age range for `row_number()`.  The earlier version tried to use a shortcut that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will give **all** policy_id that have the max total in a range.  [To simplify what it is doing have made the sub-query  not shown included].

```
SELECT X.policy_id, Y.max_ntotal, Y.Age FROM
  ( <ZZ> ) AS X JOIN
  ( SELECT MAX(count) as max_ntotal, Age FROM ( <ZZ> ) AS BB GROUP By Age ) AS Y 
  WHERE X.ntotal = Y.max_ntotal AND X.Age = Y.Age
```

I had my own `<ZZ>` query and got results like this -

```
13  1193    15-30
13  127     30-60
3   127     30-60
3   90      >60
```

YOUR example `<ZZ>` IS -

```
    SELECT o.policy_id, count(o.policy_id) as ntotal, CASE  
    WHEN c.Age BETWEEN 18 and 30 then '18 - 30'
    WHEN c.Age BETWEEN 31 and 60 then '31 - 60'
        else 'above 60' end as Age    
    FROM Orders o INNER JOIN Customer c ON (o.customer_id=c.customer_id)
    GROUP BY Age, o.policy_id
```

Comment: Almost certainly sorry - was a "something like this" response.  If you don't solve in a few hours I will look again (not near computers)

Comment: haha, no prob. It's almost 2 am here in Austria, I'll have a look at it in the morning, but thanks!